# Akka: Get total number of actors

Tags: java, akka

Is there an easy way to get the total number of all living Actors of an ActorSystem (with the Java8 API)?

It would be useful for me for debugging my application: I create Actors in many different places and want to be sure that they all terminate correctly. An actor children counter would help me to see if the total number goes up or stays approximately the same when I run my application over weeks.

Comment: Would having a single counter actor listening on a distributed channel where all other actors post a "im here" message on startup be a feasible option for your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I would also have to supervise all created actors in many different places to decrease the counter which would be a lot of work.

Comment: I think you can just register a deathwatch for them the moment you receive the "im here" message of their startup, not too much work, unless I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Thanks, yes that would work. But I have implemented now the approach from @Denis because this works without any modification for all my other actors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an actor that would send Identify() messages to all the actors in the actor system and then count replies. The caveat is that actors can be created/deleted while these Identify messages are being processed and some actors may be too busy to respond in time. So the count needs to be treated as approximate, which is probably ok for your purposes. Below is some uncompiled and untested code but it should give you an idea:

```scala
import akka.actor._

import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration

object CounterActor {
  case class CountRequest(requestId : String, timeout : FiniteDuration)
  case class FinishCounting(requestId : String, originalSender : ActorRef)
  case class CountResponse(requestId : String, count : Int)
}

class CounterActor extends Actor with Timers {
  import CounterActor._
  var counters = Map[String, Int]()

  def receive = {
    case CountRequest(requestId, timeout) =>
      counters = counters.updated(requestId, 0)
      context.actorSelection("/user/*") ! Identify(requestId)
      timers.startSingleTimer("timeout", FinishCounting(requestId, sender()), timeout)

    case ActorIdentity(cId, ref) =>
      counters = counters.updated(cId.toString, counters.getOrElse(cId.toString, 0) + 1)
      ref.foreach { ref =>
        context.actorSelection(ref.path / "*") ! Identify(cId)
      }

    case FinishCounting(requestId, originalSender) =>
      originalSender ! CountResponse(requestId, counters.getOrElse(requestId, 0))
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the approach and your code :), but this would give me only the direct child actors of `/user/` not the grand (grand-...) children.

Comment: You're right, it is not recursive. But it is easily fixable. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, now it works for me (with minor modifications to get the code compiled). It's difficult to set the correct timeout but it's perfect for my debugging purpose and works without changing any actors.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively call `children` on The Guardian actor (`/user:`) and do a depth-first traversal to get a count of your actors. This may not be exact because some actors may have been created or removed while this operation is taking place. In a *steady* state environment, you should get an exact count.

NOTE: I've not tested this.

Comment: Sounds reasonable for me. But how can I get the children from an `ActorRef`?